# SOAPMessage в String

Tags: java, xml

Как можно конвертировать SOAPMessage в String так, чтобы не было одиночных тегов, 
т.е. например, вместо

```
<ns1:Header/>
```

было

```
<ns1:Header></ns1:Header>
```

Answer (score 1):

Вообще это проблема канонизации `xml`. Она включает в себя не только проблему пустых тегов. Собственно решение в лоб возможно при помощи [библиотеки от apache](http://santuario.apache.org) примерно так

```
SOAPMessage soapMessage = ...;
SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();
Canonicalizer canonicalizer =Canonicalizer.getInstance(Canonicalizer.ALGO_ID_C14N_OMIT_COMMENTS);
byte[] xml= canonicalizer.canonicalizeSubtree(soapPart);
```